# How to reload graph in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is there a function that resets the graph to it's freshly loaded state?  I've tried cy.reset() but that just resets zoom and pan, not restoring to the virgin graph.

Also is there a way to restore all removed elements?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `cy.elements().remove()` and `cy.add()` with the same graph data.

Comment: Thanks Max.  Is it possible to request this function for the next release?

Comment: It's already there.http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/graph-manipulation/cy.load

Comment: Thanks Max! I called `cy.elements().remove()` and `cy.add()`, but some styling on the nodes is missing. I tried to call `cy.style()` and `cy.resize()`, but it didn't fix the styling. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Save in a variable the elements you removed, e.g.:

```
const elsRemoved = cy.elements().remove();
```

Then, for restoring them simply call:

```
elsRemoved.restore();
```

Refer to https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.restore for more info

Answer (score 0):

With data (here, a `.cyjs` file exported from Cytoscape), loaded via a function into Cytoscape.js, and redrawn at the click of a button.

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='cy'></div>

  <script>
  $.getJSON("ontology2.cyjs", function (data) {
    var cy = cytoscape({
      container: document.getElementById('cy'),
      elements: data.elements,
      // ...
      });

    // Reset graph:
    $('button.reset')
        .on("click", function() {
            cy.remove('node["*"]');
            cy.add(data.elements);
        });
    });
  </script>

  <button class="reset">Reset</button>
<body>
```

[image: cytoscape.js reset button demo]

- Node toggle functionality via code by "Chiarg A.M." and suggestion by "nensimons" at [Hide and Show Child Nodes on Node Tap Cytoscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41506664/hide-and-show-child-nodes-on-node-tap-cytoscape)