# How can I refresh Cytoscape after add a new node?

Tags: cytoscape.js, arbor.js

My Cytoscape is using arbor layout and I've loaded some nodes in initialization process.
All worked fine. The nodes was created and moving some time until all stabilizes.

Now, with a button, I've added a new node:

```
function addNode() {
    var eles = cy.add([
       { group: "nodes", data: { id: 'zz', name: 'MyNewNode', weight: 450, faveColor: '#F5A45D', faveShape: 'rectangle' }, position: { x: 100, y: 100 } },
       { group: "edges", data: { source: 'zz', target: 'a', faveColor: '#F5A45D', strength: 1 } }
    ]);
}
```

But, as you can see, I need to specify the position of new node.
How can I force all nodes to reacomodate, so I can add other nodes without concern about positions?

Comment: Nevermind. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391899/how-to-reload-graph-in-cytoscape-js and try `cy.load( cy.elements('*').jsons() );` with success.

Comment: `cy.load()` just runs the layout after adding the nodes.  So you could alternatively add nodes at arbitrary positions and apply a layout.

Comment: How can I do that and what is the difference?

Comment: `cy.add(eles); cy.layout(opts);` has the same end result more or less than `cy.load()`, but `cy.load()` will introduce more overhead because you're loading a whole new graph rather than modifying the existing one a bit.

Comment: When I do `cy.add(eles)` I must concern each element position and I do not want to do that. My solution is to use laytout type `arbor`, add an element and do a `load()` with same content. So, the arbor will rearrange the elements in best position and keeps the layout nice..

Comment: If you use a layout for positioning, you can safely add elements with an arbitrary position -- like `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` -- and then run the layout.

Comment: Ok, I understood. My layout don't have positioning. I do not know how many nodes the user will add, because He is in a kind of "node editor". I must use Arbor. Thanks!