# Hide and Show Child Nodes on Node Tap Cytoscape

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to create a collapsible tree structure in Cytoscape using breadthfirst layout, to replicate the [D3 collapsible tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083).

I am trying to replicate this type of click action on nodes, but adding restore functionality in addition - [Images & breadthfirst layout](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/aedff159b0df05ccfaa5/)

The reason I chose Cytoscape is because I had a scenario where the tree would have nodes with more than 1 parent.

I have tried to add a tap event using the following code:

```
cy.on('tap', 'node', function() {
    if (this.scratch().restData == null) {
       // Save node data and remove
       this.scratch({
            restData: this.connectedEdges().targets().remove()
       });
    } else {
       // Restore the removed nodes from saved data
       this.scratch().restData.restore();
       this.scratch({
            restData: null
       });
    }
}
```

But, this is successful only to collapse and expand its immediate child nodes (rest of the nodes are still visible) and also causes problem when I tap on leaf nodes.

If anyone knows a way to expand and collapse a node, please help.

**Edit**: Guys, if anyone knows the solution for a simple multilevel tree also, that would also be a good start...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `d3.js` and the tag should probably be removed.  If you are interested in d3, though, `cytoscape` looks like it produces what `d3` would call a [force tree](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/95aa92e2f4e8345aaa55a4a94d41ce37).

Answer (score 6):

I have found a few options to achieve this effect.

1. **Using remove and restore.** When the tree is loaded, the nodes' children are stored.

   ```
   var childrenData = new Map(); //holds nodes' children info for restoration
   var nodes = elems.nodes
   for(var x = 0; x < nodes.length; x++){
     var curNode = cy.$("#" + nodes[x].data.id);
     var id = curNode.data('id');
     //get its connectedEdges and connectedNodes
     var connectedEdges = curNode.connectedEdges(function(){
       //filter on connectedEdges
       return !curNode.target().anySame( curNode );
     });
     var connectedNodes = connectedEdges.targets();
     //and store that in childrenData
     //removed is true because all children are removed at the start of the graph
     childrenData.set(id, {data:connectedNodes.union(connectedEdges), removed: true}); 
   }
   ```

   This data can then be removed and restored on a node click, similar to your original code. I used Cytoscape's Images collapsing tree demo as the base for my example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97dnd915/)
2. **Using the display attribute of a node.** Because the nodes are hidden and not removed, their connected edges and nodes are still accessible, so you don't have to store the data beforehand.

   ```
   cy.on('tap', 'node', function(){
     //if the node's children have been hidden
     //getting the element at 1 because the element at 0 is the node itself
     //want to check if its children are hidden
     if (this.connectedEdges().targets()[1].style("display") == "none"){
       //show the nodes and edges
       this.connectedEdges().targets().style("display", "element");
     } else {
       //hide the children nodes and edges recursively
       this.successors().targets().style("display", "none");
     }
   });
   ```

   ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLko7pcu/))
3. There is also a Cytoscape expansion on GitHub with the name **cytoscape.js-expand-collapse**. I have not personally used it, but its description matches the functionality you describe:

   > A Cytsocape.js extension to expand/collapse nodes for better management of complexity of compound graphs

Answer (score 5):

I replaced this line of code:

```
 restData: this.connectedEdges().targets().remove()
```

with this one:

```
restData: this.successors().targets().remove()
```

and this code now collapses children and grandchildren nodes (only tested on 3 levels) and leaf nodes no longer collapse into their parent when clicked.

Comment: I spent a lot of time with the solution provided by l-boken - which works well on included data but not imported data (latter: .cyjs file exported from Cytoscape, then loaded into Cytoscape.js).  While the imported data looked, programmed similarly to the example provided, I could not resolve this line (and downstream dependents): `var curNode = cy.$("#" + nodes[x].data.id);`. The code provided in the question + this answer provided a simple solution.

Comment: Thanks! This is working for me but how do I make it hide in the beginning? Right now, when it renders, it is first visible and hides only when I click it.